# Reading out two sensors via Com-Port at the same time

Tags: serial, arduino-ide, arduino-nano

I have two Arduino Nano Every and a sensor connected to each of them. Here is what's happening:

- I upload the sketch to the first Arduino on Com4 and see its output is correct via the Serial Monitor
- I open a new instance of the Arduino-software, upload the same sketch to the second Arduino on Com6 and see its output is correct. However, in the meantime the Arduino on Com4 has stopped sending or receiving data
- If I close the second IDE-instance and re-upload the sketch to the first Arduino on Com4, it starts working again.

So, essentially I have two Arduinos which I can't read out at the same time.

The sensors are not connected, so I don't know where the problem is. Shouldn't the Com-Ports be independent?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

UPDATE, self answer:

It was a broken USB cable.

Answer (score 1):

> Shouldn't the Com-Ports be independent?

Not in the Arduino IDE, no. Basically the IDE is [expletive deleted] when it comes to using more than one board at a time.

You're better off using a proper serial terminal program, not the "serial monitor" in the IDE. Something like Teraterm or Putty, where you can have multiple instances on different ports at once.

Comment: Interestingly, the same happens with Putty..

Comment: you could write a monitoring sketch in Processing ... https://processing.org/

Comment: Or upgrade to UECIDE that has much much better port handling.

Comment: I actually used LabView in the first place which usually has no difficulties handling multiple ports at once. However, it doesn't work as well ... and you also see that the LED stops blinking, so I assume it's not just a software problem?

Comment: Maybe the firmware in the ATSAMD isn't handling a USB disconnection (LineState change) properly, or maybe the client software isn't opening the port right (Setting LineState).

Comment: It is kind of ironic that the chip they chose to implement the USB interface is far more powerful than the chip that you as a user get to program.

Comment: @Majenko, it is ATmega4809 20 MHz, 48kB flash, 6 kB SRAM; SAMD11 48 MHz, 16 kB flash, 4kB SRAM

Comment: Yes. Like I said. A slow 8 bit vs a faster 32 bit. More power in the USB interface.

Comment: I use multiple instances of the Arduino IDE open at once to solve this problem, and it works well for multiple serial connections from multiple boards at once. You get one serial connection per instance open. I used to have multiple versions of the IDE installed for this to work but I think it works fine just running multiple instances of the program at once now. If not, just run multiple zip-installed instances of the IDE from different unzipped folders.

Comment: Also, I have a Python demo to read serial data from an Arduino if anyone wants it (and if I won't be suspended for sharing a link to it, of course). It's on my GitHub I believe. It makes logging from Arduino really easy and versatile, and shows how to get a PC program and Arduino talking.